# glfwCreateWindow() does not work after setting window hints

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, glfw

I'm following a tutorial which uses `glfwWindowHint()` to set the version of GLFW that he is using. He's on OSX and I'm on Windows. I have the exact same code as his. When I do this:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
```

And then this:

```
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 360, "Modern OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
```

It always returns `NULL`. But in the tutorial he said that setting the window hints was necessary to use the code that the program uses. When I take out the window hints the window is created sucessfully, but then it crashes (because of the other code that probably required the window hint changes).

[image]

I'm on Windows XP. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, this code should *always* return NULL on OSX, as OSX supports OpenGL >=3 only in core profiles, while this code requests a compatibility profile.

On Windows, a compatibility profile of that version *might* be supported. But this will depend on the GPU and the drivers you have installed. It might very well be the case that your system does simply not support GL3.2. Make sure you are using recent drivers. And check what GL version your GPU actually supports. One thing you could try though is setting the `GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT` hint to `GL_FALSE`.

Comment: The GL version is 2.0.6747. As for the driver I don't know how to get that. Is that included in my PC documentation that I bought it with?

Comment: For "modern" GL 3.x on desktop machnines, you will need either a nVidia Geforce 8-Series (introduced 2006) or better (Gefroce 9, GTS/GTX/...), a ATI/AMD Radeon HD2000 (introduced also 2006) or better or Intel HD 2000 (introduced with Sandy Brdige in 2011), or better. So if you have one of those GPUs, you can try getting a driver update. If not, you can not get hw-accelerated GL 3.x.